# Probability density algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random

I'm not sure that the name for what I need is ***probability density*** but anyway.

I'd like to find a function or algorithm for generating random numbers in the specified range with specified chance and linear change.

For example, specified range and chances are:

[image: Chart of chances]

Range from -10 to 15.

Chaces are: [[-10, 5], [-5, 0], [3, 5], [10, 30], [15, 0]]

The result after generating a number could be any numbers from that range except -5 and 15. So could be -10, -9, -8, -7 ... 13, 14.

And chance to get -10 is 5 units.
-5 is 0 units.
3 is 5 units.

So -9 will appear with 4 units chance and -8 with 3 units chance etc.

And in this case, the most common numbers should appear about 10 because 10 has 30 units chance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn the probabilities into numbers from 0 to 1 that sum up to 1:

```
 const chances = [[-10, 5], [-5, 0], [3, 5], [10, 30], [15, 0]];
 const total = chances.reduce((total, [_, v]) => total + v, 0);
 chances.forEach(it => it[1] /= total);
```

Now you can generate a random number, and find the first value where the sum of probabilities before is bigger than that number:

```
let random = Math.random();
const result = chances.find(([_, p]) => (random -= p) < 0)[0];
```

Comment: Thank you, but your algorythm for specified numbers only. It won't generate numbers between them. It won't generate -9, -8, -7, -6, -4, -3, -2 ... 12, 13

Comment: @user3055346 but it is quite easy to change it accordingly